# when sending a post request to node js, I get an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

My problem is when i send with react js axios post a request to the server i get req.body empty

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const config = require('config');
const testRoutes = require('./routes/test');

const app = express();
const PORT = config.get('port') || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({ extended: true }));


app.use('/api/test', testRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Сервер запустился на порте ${PORT}`));
```

**form component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import './login-page.css';

const LoginPage = (props) => {
    const { phone, password, inputControl, handlerLogin } = props;
    return (
        <div className="login-page">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-left col-lg-6">
                        <div className="wrapper-col">
                            <h4>Войти</h4>
                            <div className="separator">
                                <hr />
                                <span>заполните форму</span>
                                <hr />
                            </div>
                            <form onSubmit={handlerLogin}>
                                <div className="mb-3">
                                    <input className="form-control" 
                                    type="text"
                                    name="phone"
                                    placeholder="Телефон"
                                    value={phone}
                                    onChange={inputControl} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="mb-3">
                                    <input className="form-control" 
                                    type="password"
                                    name="password"
                                    placeholder="Пароль" 
                                    value={password}
                                    onChange={inputControl} />
                                </div>
                                <button className="btn btn-lg btn-login mb-2" 
                                type="submit">Войти</button>
                                <Link to="/recovery">Забыли пароль?</Link>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-right col-lg-6">
                        <div className="wrapper-col">
                            <h4>Нет аккаунта? Присоединяйтесь к нам!</h4>
                            <p>После регистрации у вас будет возможность как выполнять заказы, так и заказывать услуги на Yams.</p>
                            <Link to="/registration" className="btn">Зарегестрироваться</Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default LoginPage;
```

**handler**

*When i send via new FormData to the server i get an empty object*

```
handlerLogin = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('handlerLogin()');

        const formData = new FormData(e.target);

        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/test/', formData)
    }
```

**file routes**

```
const { Router } = require('express');

const router = Router();

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body); //req.body -> {}
})

module.exports = router;
```

**handler**

*But when I send from a regular JSON object*

```
handlerLogin = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('handlerLogin()');

        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/test/', {name: 'test1', surname: 'test2'});
    }
```

*I receive the sent data on the server, Works as it should*

```
const { Router } = require('express');

const router = Router();

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body); // req.body ---> {name: 'test1', surname: 'test2'}
})

module.exports = router;
```

Help solve this problem, I will be very grateful, thanks!

Comment: are the values in `formData` correct?

Answer (score 1):

FormData requests (which support file uploads) send multipart formatted data, but the only body parsing middleware you have is setup for JSON formatted data.

You need something which can handle the type of body you are sending.

[multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme) is probably the most popular middleware for handling multipart data.

---

You also must make sure that `e.target` is a form with successful controls in it. It could be fine, but we can’t see it so we can’t tell.

Comment: Hello, I have changed, please can look again!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — `FormData` objects are always converted to multipart: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-multipart/form-data-encoding-algorithm

Comment: @Sardor — Form looks like it won't cause any problems here, so you just need to sort the middleware.

Comment: Interesting. At first I was going to point out that that's the `fetch` spec and the OP is using axios, but the `XMLHttpRequest` spec refers to the `fetch` spec for "extracting" the body, so it does the same thing...